# The current thread on the server changes after leaving the server?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

In a MVC application, when I go to the client and return using AJAX, is the current thread from before the same current thread when I return or is it a new thread from the threadpool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be but there is no guarantee and if that happens it would be mere luck.

From [Performing Asynchronous Work, or Tasks, in ASP.NET Applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx)

> New requests are received by HTTP.sys, a kernel driver.  HTTP.sys posts the request to an I/O completion port on which IIS listens.  IIS picks up the request on one of its thread pool threads and calls into ASP.NET where ASP.NET immediately posts the request to the CLR ThreadPool and returns a pending status to IIS.

and it continues

> To execute it, we raise all of the pipeline events and the modules and handlers in the pipeline work on the request, typically while remaining on the same thread, but they can alternatively handle these events asynchronously.

So for one request you can be on the same thread.

As your AJAX request will be a new call to the http.sys kernel driver and the handover to the managed thread pool it is highly unlikely that the same thread will be re-used. If it did your web application would use way more threads then it is capable off, slowing the webserver to a crawl.

If you want to mimic that the same thread is used you must hookup in one of the state managment related [event life cycle events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)